# Why does the expression `Object.singleton_class.instance_method(:refine)` raise `NameError`?

Tags: ruby

As we know, the method `Module#refine` is the private instance method in the `Module` class:

```
% Module.private_instance_methods(false)
[:remove_const, :method_added, :append_features, :method_removed, 
:method_undefined, :extend_object, :prepend_features, :using, :refine, 
:initialize, :initialize_copy, :initialize_clone, :public, :protected, 
:module_function, :private, :included, :extended, :prepended]
```

This means that `Object` class itself could invoke `refine` method using `Object#send` or `BasicObject#__send__`, because `Object.singleton_class.ancestors.include?(Module)` is true.

But the actual `undefined method` error raises when `Object.refine` is executed:

```
# ./tmp/mytest.rb
Module.private_instance_methods(false).map do |m|
  begin
    p [m, Object.singleton_class.instance_method(m)]
  rescue StandardError => e
    p [m, e.exception]
  end
end
```

The output is this. The `refine` method is in the middle.

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
% ruby ./tmp/mytest.rb
[:remove_const, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#remove_const>]
[:method_added, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#method_added>]
[:append_features, #<NameError: undefined method `append_features' for class `#<Class:Object>'>]
[:method_removed, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#method_removed>]
[:method_undefined, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#method_undefined>]
[:extend_object, #<NameError: undefined method `extend_object' for class `#<Class:Object>'>]
[:prepend_features, #<NameError: undefined method `prepend_features' for class `#<Class:Object>'>]
[:using, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#using>]
[:refine, #<NameError: undefined method `refine' for class `#<Class:Object>'>]
[:initialize, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#initialize>]
[:initialize_copy, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#initialize_copy>]
[:initialize_clone, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#initialize_clone>]
[:public, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#public>]
[:protected, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#protected>]
[:module_function, #<NameError: undefined method `module_function' for class `#<Class:Object>'>]
[:private, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#private>]
[:included, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#included>]
[:extended, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#extended>]
[:prepended, #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:Object>#prepended>]
```

In the above result, other than `refine` method, `append_features`, `prepend_features`, `extend_object` and `module_function` method raise `NameError`, whereas other methods succeed method lookup.

It looks so curious that I want to know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspection it looks like the `:refine` is an  `UnboundMethod` but I found this by `pry`ing around.  From pry console:

```
Module.private_instance_methods(:false)
```

You'll notice:

```
 [ 76]                     refine(arg1)                    Module (unbound)
```

This [documentation should explain](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/UnboundMethod.html) the `NameError` getting raised in your code example

Comment: Try `Object.singleton_class.private_instance_methods.grep(/refine/)` and `Module.private_instance_methods.grep(/refine/)`. I want to know the difference between the above two expression. Your answer doesn't seem to answer my question.